# ‘RoutingHTTPServer/RoutingConnection.h’ file not found

Tags: java, ios, iphone, macos, appium-ios

I am facing the below issue while installing WebDriverAgent using Terminal.

```
Appium : 1.6.4
Xcode : 8.3
MAC : 10.12
```

When I run the below command

```
xcodebuild build test -project /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination id='<udid>' -configuration Debug
```

I got the below logs

```
usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgentLib/Routing/FBWebServer.m:12:9: 'RoutingHTTPServer/RoutingConnection.h' file not found
```

Please find the attached screenshot:

[image]
Kindly provide the solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is issue with the WebDriverAgent. RoutingConnection.h file may be missing in webdriveragent project. Try to uninstall and install the appium and run the webdriveragent by providing proper provisioning profile and developer certificate.